# how to tackle a special condition in map of java8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Question` class as follows:

```
public class Question {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private boolean isAdded;
    ...
    getters and setters
}
```

I want all questions from a list of questions whose isAdded=true appended by ':' and if question name is Special than in that case Special-type value.

The final String should look like this:

```
questionname1:questionname2:Special-type value:questionname4
```

I have written:

```
List<String> slist = questionList.stream().filter(q -> q.isAdded() == true).map(name-> name.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());

String final = String.join(":", slist);
```

I get all string names appended by : but do not get type value if question name is Special.

Please let me know what changes should be made.

Comment: instead of `q.isAdded() == true` just simply write `q.isAdded()`

Comment: You cannot name a variable `final`. Besides that, if you want that string result, use `Collectors.joining(":")` in the first place, instead of producing a `List` first.

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
  list.stream()
      .filter(Question::isAdded)
      .map(item-> item.getName().equals("Special") ? item.getType() : item.getName())
      .collect(Collectors.joining(":"))
```

Comment: in the statement .map(item-> item.getName().equals("Special") ? item.getType() : item.getName()) i need to write it as .map(item-> item.getName().equals("Special") ? item.getName()+ ":" + item.getType() : item.getName()), but it is not working. What am i missing here?

Comment: why do you want to write it that way. when u say not working? what are u getting

Answer (score 1):

You can include a condition in the lambda expression passed to `map()`:

```
.map(q -> q.getName().equals("Special") ? "Special-type value" : q.getName())
```

And the full `Stream` pipeline would be:

```
List<String> slist = 
    questionList.stream()
                .filter(q -> q.isAdded())
                .map(q -> q.getName().equals("Special") ? "Special-type value" : q.getName())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

BTW, if you want to join the `List` to a single `String`, you can do it directly:

```
String finalValue = 
    questionList.stream()
                .filter(q -> q.isAdded())
                .map(q -> q.getName().equals("Special") ? "Special-type value" : q.getName())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(":"));
```

P.S. it wasn't clear from your phrasing if you wanted the String "Special-type value" to be used when the name is "Special", or to use some other value which you didn't specify how to obtain.

Comment: I tried like questionList.stream()
                .filter(q -> q.isAdded())
                .map(q -> q.getName().equals("Special") ? q.getName()+";"+q.getValue() : q.getName())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); But it didn't worked.